# Can I connect Android device (Galaxy Tab) to my iPhone to use its 3G data plan?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, ios

I have two devices:

1. iPhone with sim card, including data option
2. Galaxy tab without sim card

As the iPhone always has an internet connection, I want to use it for the Galaxy Tab as well. Of course I could just swap the sim card, but I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

Beginning with IOS 4.3, the IPhone also has an option to create a personal hotspot to allow other devices to use its internet connection. 
Unfortunately, this only seems to work over Bluetooth or USB.

As USB is out of question, it looks like Bluetooth is my only hope. Therefore my question:

Is there any way to convince my Galaxy Tab to use a Bluetooth as "Internet connection" ? If not, is there any other way to achieve what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: Of course I could also turn it around and put the sim card in my galaxy tab and then connect the iPhone via wireless to Android. But the iPhone is really the main device and I don't need the internet connection on my tab too often when I'm not home.

Comment: note that strictly speaking, hotspot strictly refers to a Wifi access point. Bluetooth "access point" or USB tethering usually are not called hotspots.

Answer (score 2):

MyWi for iphone will do it but may need to install wpa_supplicant.adhocfix on galaxy to accept adhoc network.  I did this on my nook color and it works really well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I need to jailbreak my iPhone for MyWi. If this is the only solution, I might consider jailbreaking.

Comment: @socken23 AFAIK, you have to jailbreak or pay up for tethering on the iPhone (similarly to rooting on Android or pay up for tethering)

Comment: I tested PDANet now which works quite similar to MyWi but is free (didn't know that MyWi is $20). The Galaxy Tab doesn't see the wireless network yet. Suppose thats what you meant with wpa_supplicant.adhocfix, will check that!

Comment: There is no need to root to use tethering on android. It has been a part of the basic OS since 2.1 or 2.2. It is up to your carrier to disable it if they want to. At least T mobile does not disable it. Though they do offer a plan addon if you'd like to pay them for a feature that you can already use.

Comment: @Tim is right, wireless hotspot is a standard part of Froyo, no need for root *(unless your device doesn't have a compatible WiFi chipset, or your phone company disables it)*. Anyway this is beside the point and not helping the OP so I'll leave it here.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to connect via BT. You can do it via wifi. Turn on tethering on the iPhone. Go to wifi settings and ensure the iPhone is not connected to a wifi device. Then go to your tab and open wifi connection settings. Do a wifi search and it'll find the iPhone. Connect the tab wifi to the hotspot which is the iPhone.

Comment: Actually, you got me confused there. I checked with a friends phone and you are correct! However, it doesn't work on my phone. The reason is visible on this page: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3574, Sharing the connection over WiFi only works on IPhone 4, unfortunately I still have 3GS so I'm out of luck. Thanks for the hint though!

Comment: [comment by anonymous] Dont forget the password, a friend of mine said it didn't work but she neglected to put in the password given on the Iphone, in the personal hotspot section in settings. (sorry but some things have to be made fool proof!)